# How do I extract a horizontal line from a PDF file using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

[image]I am using iTextSharp to read text out of a PDF file. I am using the LocationTextExtractionStrategy class for this purpose. I have a specific document which has a horizontal line spanning the entire width of the page and located near the footer. This line serves as a visual partition between the body text and the footer contents.

How can I get iTextSharp to read this line?

Thanks,
Sau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying idea is to implement IEventListener, and then listen to PathRenderInfo events. These are essentially called whenever the parser hits a drawing instruction.

From PathRenderInfo you can easily extract the line(s) that is being drawn. And then you can simply look for the line with the lowest y-value (since the origin is typically at the bottom left of the page).

I had this code lying around in Java, but it should be very similar for .net.

```
public class FooterLine implements IEventListener {

    private PdfPage pdfPage = null;
    private double footerLineY = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    public FooterLine(PdfPage pdfPage)
    {
        this.pdfPage = pdfPage;
        process();
    }

    public double getFooterLineY()
    {
        return footerLineY;
    }

    private void process() {
        PdfCanvasProcessor processor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(this);
        processor.processPageContent(pdfPage);        
    }

    @Override
    public void eventOccurred(IEventData iEventData, EventType eventType) {
        if(eventType == EventType.RENDER_PATH)
            processPath((PathRenderInfo) iEventData);
    }

    private void processPath(PathRenderInfo pri)
    {
        for(Subpath subpath : pri.getPath().getSubpaths())
        {
            Point p0 = subpath.getStartPoint();
            Point p1 = subpath.getLastPoint();

            // only horizontal lines are allowed
            if(p0.getY() != p1.getY())
                continue;

            footerLineY = java.lang.Math.min(footerLineY, p0.getY());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: please be aware that such lines often actually are very thin rectangles, sometimes even 1x1 bitmaps stretched to a long line, once I even saw a horizontal line created as very wide, very short vertical line. Thus, there may be complication in the detail.

Comment: Hi Joris, Thanks for your response. I was unable to find the classes IEventData,IEventListener  and PathRenderInfo  in the .NET port of iTextSharp.  Github URL: https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/tree/develop/src/core)

Comment: Try it again with the latest version of iText. That'd be iText7.